# ASP.NET MVC: Why is my Model null on HttPost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have absolutely no idea why my model is null when I'm trying to submit this form with only ONE field, a dropdownlistfor selected value.

The Get works just fine, and the Model is defintively not null. But everytime I try to submit the form, model is always null and I have no idea why at the moment:

Model:

```
[Required]
public string SelectedOrderStatus { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> OrderStatuses { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @model Webstore.Models.OrderViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderId)


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Change Order Status for order: @Model.OrderId</h4>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Orderstatus, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedOrderStatus, new SelectList(Model.OrderStatuses, "Value", "Text"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedOrderStatus)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save Order Status" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


}
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, OrderViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                Order orderToEdit = _context.Orders.Find(id);

                orderToEdit.Orderstatus = (Orderstatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(Orderstatus), model.SelectedOrderStatus);

                _context.Entry(orderToEdit).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

I would appreaciate a lot if you would help me out here!

Regards!

Comment: your model (upper) is not full, in view you have `model.Orderstatus` and `Model.OrderId`

Comment: model.OrderStatus is just a label.

model.SelectedOrderStatus is the only value I want from the form. SelectedOrderStatus is the selected item in the Selectlist model.OrderStatuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if `FormCollection collection` have value which you need. So your `Edit` methods will looks like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, FormCollection collection)
{
   // rest of logic here
}
```

Optionally, check in `Request[..]`, like here:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    var value1 = Request["SelectedOrderStatus"];
}
```

Of course this is not as beatifull solution as it should be, but there is some problem with model blinding which I cannot resolve without rest of code.

Comment: That Request line sure did the trick, finally! This problem litterally gave me headache.

Thank you for responding so quickly! I really appreciate it!